# Is log-link function important in this case?

Tags: regression, link-function

I have a positive count response $Y$ (number of times that a particular pattern was observed within a single day) and positive count independent variables $X_{1}, X_{2}$ (that are associated with the pattern).

In particular, the domain for both dependant and independent variables include zero, i.e

$$Y\in \left \{ 0,1,2,3,... \right \}, X_{1},X_{2}\in \left \{ 0,1,2,3,... \right \}$$

The number of samples that I have is around $5000$. I want to fit a regression of the following form

$Y = a_{0} + a_{1}X_{1} +a_{2}X_{2}$

1. Can I run a simple regression, without link functions as both sides are defined on the same domain??
2. If I have to use a log-link function, then because $Y$ can be zero, how do I handle the $log(0)=-\infty$ responses.
3. If I use a GLM framework is there a problem that I do not know the distribution that $Y$ follow, I assume that if I use a Poisson and regress that $X_{1},X_{2}$ on the expect parameter $\lambda$ of the Poisson there would be no problem?

Which of the 3 approaches might me the most appropriate?

Comment: I would probably use a log-link in this case. However, if $\min(Y)$ is far away from zero you might be able to get away without the log-link. Hard to say really without seeing a plot of the data + specific context

Comment: @jcken The $Y \in\left \{ 0,1,2,3,... \right \}$ as well as $X_{1},X_{2}\in \left \{ 0,1,2,3,... \right \}$. And the problem is that $log(0)=-\infty$ and I do not know how I regress something on $-\infty$.

Comment: You really need to tell us some more details, if you want some more than a simple yes or no ..

Comment: @jken: Your comment shows a misunderstanding: You transform the response, that is not using a link function. You should be using a glm (generalized linear model) then that $\log 0$ problem will disappear, because you are transforming the (estimated) expectation, not the count itself.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen So, I should work on a GLM framework? But, if the counts on $Y$ are not coming from a known distribution, what family should we use??

Comment: You need to tell us more details: What are you counting, sample size, your goal!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I edited the post, I hope I wrote things clearer this time.